# How in android in AlaramManger and BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I want set the alarm at the specified time and implement the notification at the specified time(in a day) by using **BroadcastReceiver** and **AlaramManager**.

It alarmed specified time. After when I run the app, it again alarm even though it's not the time I set.

In other words, when I set the alarm 9:21 pm and I run the app after 9:21 pm, the notification is generated.

I just want to make the alarm notification at the specified time I set and app doesn't run.
Also, when I run the app, it doesn't alarm.

How can I fix it?

This is my BroadcastReceiver Code -

```
public class BroadcastD extends BroadcastReceiver{
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        showNotification();

}

    public void showNotification() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
           .getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTicker("Ticket")
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Context")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AlarmManager am ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        AlarmHATT alarmHATT = new AlarmHATT(getApplicationContext());
        alarmHATT.Alarm();
}
 public class AlarmHATT {
    private Context context;

    public AlarmHATT(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Alarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent( context.getApplicationContext(), BroadcastD.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 21, 21, 0);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: It´s a normal behaviour that alarmManager starts if you set a time that´s in the past. You can´t avoid, only by set the correct time.

Comment: What is the other way that I can avoid alarm? If you know, please teach me.  Thank You.

Comment: just don´t set the time in the past. The question is, WHY do you want to set time from the past? This makes no sense, nobody need to be notified for a event that has passed.....

Comment: How can I set the time reapeatable alarm in a day? I want notification specified time I set just once in a day. And at the time after I set, when I run the app, notification doesn't do.  I don't understand your comment. Please correct my code. I am very urgent. Thank you for your help

Comment: you have to set it to the next day, something like `calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)+1` . But really, you have to learn more about AlarmManager and Calendars, these topics can´t be explained here. Read the API! AlarmManager:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html Calendar:https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html. And be aware of doze mode: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: I will try this! I am very thank you for your flavor.

Comment: you´re welcome. starting alarm is not as difficult as it looks like. But it´s too much to explain here, So reading the API is allways the first choice..

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having the alarm fire immediately, configure your start time with the `Calendar` like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

And then if the time you are setting has already passed today, you need to set the calendar to the following day with:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

That will avoid having your alarm fire immediately because it was set to a time that already passed earlier in the day.

Then continue to use `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` as your starting time.

Answer (score -2):

Try below code to `set alarm` on a specified time.

```
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```